# Read Multiple lines in log file and set as 1 line in CSV file

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, logging, batch-processing

We have multiple lines for each revision in a SVN log file. Sometimes there is only one revision per ID, and sometimes there maybe more( I have seen 30). 
Each revison is set by a delimter '--------------------------" 
We want the re-order the output into a CSV with 1 line for each revision.
See link to attached Input log and output log
Here are links to output & input: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vagfdr4foowsegf/output.csv
https://www.dropbox.com/s/59l7njeehsrg5p3/svn.log
The output.csv has 5 lines. One for each revision or QUES ID

Is there a way to do it with a FOR loop?

```
[ FOR /F "delims=~" %%a in (svn.log)  echo %%a  
  set col3 = %%a 
  echo col3 col2 col1 ]
```

Comment: If you can provide an output file that is exactly what you need from the ENTIRE input file, then someone might have a clue of how the extra lines need to be processed.

Comment: I updated the output file in CSV format with the way we need it formated. All Delimeter lines "-----" removed. These are the only extra lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This handles the delimiter lines too and it seems to do what you need from your sample files.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
type "svn.log"|findstr /r /v /c:"^----------"|repl "," " "|repl "^ *([AMD] .*)\r\n" " $1" xm |repl "(^Changed paths:)\r\n" "$1" xm |repl "^[ /t]*$" "" xm |repl "\r\n\r\n" "\r\n" xm |repl "(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n" "$4,$3,$1,$2\r\n" xm  > "output.csv"
```

Expanded version also using VBS:

```
@echo off
set "fileout=%temp%\svntemp.tmp"
type "svn.log"|findstr /r /v /c:"^----------"|repl "," ";"|repl "^ *([AMD] .*)\r\n" " $1" xm |repl "(^Changed paths:)\r\n" "$1" xm |repl "\r\n" "," xm |repl ",,," "," |repl ",," "," |repl ",," "," |repl "," "\r\n" x >"%fileout%" 

(
 echo Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
 echo infile = "%fileout%"
 echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
 echo Set f1 = fso.OpenTextFile(infile, ForReading^)
 echo Do While not f1.AtEndOfStream
 echo f = f1.readline 
 echo Wscript.echo f  
 echo    if lcase(left(f,14^)^) = "changed paths:" then flag = 1 : line = "" else flag = 0 
 echo       do while flag = 1
 echo          f = f1.readline
 echo             if not lcase(left(f,9^)^) = "ques id: " then line=line + f + "; " else Wscript.echo line : Wscript.echo f : exit do 
 echo       loop
 echo loop
 echo f1.close
)>"%fileout%.vbs"

cscript /nologo "%fileout%.vbs" >"%fileout%.2"

type "%fileout%.2"|repl "(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n" "$4,$3,$1,$2\r\n" xm  > "output.csv"
del "%fileout%" "%fileout%.2" "%fileout%.vbs"
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked fine for the original input. The problem is  revisions input keeps changing from revision to revision from SVN. I just had to different QUES ID and preformed differently. I probably need to figure out SVN format for the lines. Columns in SVN Revisions, Action, Description, QUES ID. I can attach the output but i need to figure out how many diffent ways SVN outputs its data

Comment: Can you help me understand what that code is doing? It seems spaces and additional lines and comma in the description/action can throw off the script

Comment: I made the code change all commas to a space - so extra commas will not affect Excel.

Comment: I reduced the sensitivity to leading spaces and spaces in blank lines and it's not sensitive to commas, but Excel is sensitive to extra commas. The solution uses regular expressions - you need to know how they work before I can explain it. In essence the findstr removes lines starting with ------ and blank lines, and empty lines with spaces, then repl joins the lines "starting with spaces and an M" so that there are only 4 lines in total, finally it reorders those lines with a comma between them into a csv format. Provide more INPUT samples if you can.

Comment: I added the input & ouput file links. I used your new changes for the script. It seems SVN uses  M, A and D as placeholders for Modify Add and Delete.  You can run the script you created against the input and see how the record with the comma in description is affected. See files in links below https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3bswo9t5gk6b3h/svn4.log  https://www.dropbox.com/s/44yc620cv97w21s/svn5.log https://www.dropbox.com/s/kr3jiwg915l3ieg/output4.csv https://www.dropbox.com/s/2stmenpea49wvfp/output5.csv

Comment: There are 4 files above, SVN4&5.log is the input. Outpu4&5.CSV is the output i received running your last script

Comment: Try the edited code now - it is a lot more robust and the comma issue has gone.  Note that all commas in the `svn.log` are replaced with a space, to eliminate problems when importing the `.csv` into Excel.

Comment: I had another record with comma in the description and it failed. It also had bracket ) in the description.   Attached  https://www.dropbox.com/s/j51mlmv41r87p5y/output2.csv https://www.dropbox.com/s/8x06h3y1t4s2y4x/svn2.log

Comment: There is an expanded version above now: As well as repl.bat it uses VBscript to handle the comment fields, because they are freeform and unpredictable.  See how that goes - I also changed the existing commas to `;` instead of space.

Comment: Thanks. This works fine on windows 7. I can live with it. On windows XP i get the following error. See echoON.txt  and Output.csv  Using svn2.log as input svn.log https://www.dropbox.com/s/vagfdr4foowsegf/output.csv  https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1ha8swcbhqpvgp/EchoOn.txt

Comment: Did you copy `repl.bat` to the XP machine?  There are no differences in an XP machine in this regard that I am aware of - unless the XP machine is locked down and doesn't have access to Windows Scripting Host.

Comment: Yes i copied repl.bat. I will test on Windows 7 and let you know.